# Which option is more lightweight? CSS diagonal lines or small repeating .png image?

Tags: html, css, png

I want my web application to be fast and cross-browser compatible. There will be a lot of animated motion by javascript.
Is there a remarkable difference in CSS diagonal lines (by gradient) or small repeating .png image?

Comment: Why don't you benchmark it and tell us the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My general rule of thumb is that If you can do something in CSS do it in CSS! or at least that was what I was taught back in uni.

I would have thought the png would need greater bandwidth to download the file where as the CSS would require more processing power. Both of these shouldn't be to great as we are only talking about a small image / tiny bit off css so I can't see there being much in the way of performance issues.

CSS was designed to separate the content from the styling to encourage accessibility and cross-browser compatibility. (Images should only really be added in HTML when they are the content and not for styling).